# curl --data-binary with retrofit

Tags: android, curl, retrofit

I am trying to use http://pastec.io/ with Retrofit for an Android application

My question is how is the equivalent of curl

`curl -X POST --data-binary @/home/test/img/request.jpg http://localhost:4212/index/searcher`

in retrofit